# NullPointerException in custom adapter getView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, listadapter

I'm coding a custom adapter for a ListView that has a custom list to it.

obviously, I have to write the `getView` function. so here is my code:

```
/*1*/ public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
/*2*/    View vi = convertView;
/*3*/    if (convertView == null)
/*4*/        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, null);
/*5*/
/*6*/    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
/*7*/    TextView subtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTitle);
/*8*/    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
/*9*/
/*10*/   title.setText(data.get(position).getDescription().toString());
/*11*/   subtitle.setText(data.get(position).getDate().toString());
/*12*/   String img = "http://someLink/" + data.get(position).getId() + "a_t.jpg";
/*13*/   imageLoader.DisplayImage(img, image);
/*14*/   return vi;
/*15*/ }
```

But, I have noticed that on line number 6 the program crashes with a NullPointer exception.

here is my crash report:

```
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.package.mojo.NoPicAdapter.getView(NoPicAdapter.java:46)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1554)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1264)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:847)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1868)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
04-18 09:33:32.745: E/AndroidRuntime(2209):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

of course, the layout and the items themselves exist...

any thoughts?

update: when i look at the variables while debugging, I see that `vi` was not inflated (`vi == null`), why?

Comment: Could you please tell us which row of your posted code snippet corresponds to `NoPicAdapter.java:46` ?

Comment: Does your line number 6 in the above code correspond to line number 46 in NoPicAdapter? Also how are you creating the inflater object?

Comment: line 6 is actually line 46 in the original code, just edited it here for the porpoise of explaining my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change this:

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, null);
```

To this:

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, parent, false);
```

---

this is how your adapter should be:

```
public class NoPicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NewAndCalendar> {

    private ArrayList<NewAndCalendar> data;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public NoPicAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<NewAndCalendar> d) {
        super(a, R.layout.no_pic_list_item, d);
        mActivity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_pic_list_item, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.noPicTitle);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.noPicSubtitle);

        title.setText(data.get(position).getmTitle());
        subtitle.setText(data.get(position).getmPubDate());

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: changed to the second version, vi still equals null

Comment: [this](http://pastie.org/private/nipgdadde02hft9gx0f0a) is my whole code for the custom adapter

Comment: instead of extending to `BaseAdapter`, you should extend to `ArrayAdapter`. Moreover, don't set your **inflater** object as *static*, since it may cause memory leaks.

Comment: no more **static** for me.

why should I extend `ArrayAdapter` if the view is `ListView`? I took the idea for the code from fedorvlasovs' LazyAdapter

Comment: because when you use BaseAdapter, you need to take care of some other overrided methods too. However, in your case your are simply showing items in list. So its better to use ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

> vi = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity).inflate(R.layout.result_list_item, null);

if mActivity is your Activity context passed from the activity where you are creating the object of this adapter.

Comment: that did the trick, the only problem now is the very new `NullPointerException` i got from the rest of the code...

Comment: problems with implementing SAXParser I think. something is not being parsed correctly

Answer (score 1):

are you initializing inflater? if not initialize it.

```
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
```

or

```
 inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: the initialization code is in the constructor:
`inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`

Comment: and is mActivity the Activity Context u r passing from the Activity?

Comment: yes, mActivity is the activity passed on for the constructor.