# App crashing when using ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

When enabling ProGuard to obfuscate my code, it crashes my app. Without ProGuard, it works well. I've added `minifyEnabled true` and `shrinkResources true`. Are there any more rules I need to add?

This is my `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn android.support.design.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,Exceptions

-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawable { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

And here are the libraries that I use in my app:

```
dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibraryVersion"
compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"

compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseVersion"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$firebaseVersion"

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
}
```

Edit: Stacktrace:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                  at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post crash report please

Comment: @ZakiPathan Added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10822830/7320259 check this

Comment: try adding this -keep class * extends your.company.secret.package

Comment: You are missing some ProGuard lines, from Retrofit at least, recheck all of  them

Comment: @ZakiPathan I tried adding that, but it's not working.

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez I've added all the lines mentioned in the Retrofit documentation. It doesn't seem to work. What else do you think I'm missing?

Comment: @RandomyzeEverything Recheck all the required ProGuard lines for all libraries you added in your project